# Intellij Plugin SDK - create toolbar similar to find

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I am developing a plugin that can parse document contents. I need to create a toolbar similar to the one appearing for Find (Ctrl+F) that will appear when openning the document with the extension. I know how to register the action, but I don't know in which group does this appear. I have created actions for ProjectViewPopupMenu and EditorPopupMenu, but I don't know to which group this belongs. I cannot find any documentation on action groups on the IntelliJ documentation site.

Does anyone have any experience with this?

[image: find toolbar]

Comment: https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/

Comment: Thanks but not very helpful. There are a lot of references to a Find action, not one explaining in which group to add it.

Comment: Your question does not really make sense, you can add your action to any group you want. Take a look at com.intellij.openapi.fileEditor.FileEditorManagerListener#FILE_EDITOR_MANAGER, it seems more appropriate than some "action".